# Virtual ground in two-stage OpAmp for slew rate calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, slew-rate

I am reading about slew rate of two-stage OpAmp from this [page](http://mgh-courses.ece.gatech.edu/ece4430/Filmed_lectures/BasicMOSFETOpAmps/L440-SimpleMOSFETOpAmps.pdf).
However, I don't understand why the node voltage at drain of M2 or M4 is assumed to be a virtual ground here.

Could anyone explain that?

[image]

PS: I have just seen a paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261304507_Slew-rate_enhancement_for_a_single-ended_low-power_two-stage_amplifier) saying that the output voltage is also the voltage across the capacitor. 
Could you explain why the voltage across the current source M0 is almost zero?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the voltage across M0 is "almost zero"?

Comment: I infered it from the expression (2) above. (2) is only correct if the voltage across M0 is zero.

Comment: I rather think that equ. (2) correctly assumes that the voltage across M0 is CONSTANT.

Comment: Thanks. Actually (2) is only correct if the voltage across M0 is zero and (3) is correct if the voltage across M0 is zero or constant.

Comment: What actually matters for the slew rate is equ (3) only.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my opinion, the term "virtual ground" is somewhat misleading. I think the following interpretation can help:

For ac signals, any constant power supply VDD is considered to have zero ohms source resistance - hence, it is considered to be "at virtual ground" for any voltage **changes**. 
The same applies in the case under discussion: We are interested in the time behaviour of changing voltages and currents. For slew rate calculations, the transistor M4 works as a switch and, hence, its drain voltage can be considered as **constant**. Therefore, for calculation of all voltage and current **changes** (caused by large input signals driving M4 into saturation), this node can also be considered to be at "virtual ground".

In this context, it is important to realize that the given expressions "I/C" are time derivatives "dV/dt".

Note that any input step (larger than 100mV) will drive the first stage of an opamp into saturation (for a short time period) until the delayed feedback signal will bring the stage back to linear operation.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post with PS section. Could you explain why the voltage across the current source M0 is almost zero?

Comment: @LvW but this 100mV is only true for BJT's

Comment: G36, thank you for correcting me. Yes - I had only BJT`s in mind. For FETs there is another voltage limit. In any case, it must be a voltage large enough to drive the first stage into saturation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a ground, but a fixed voltage.  When the opamp gets a large input signal, that node will be slammed either full high or full low.

The reason they call it a virtual ground is because its voltage is fixed.  Since this voltage is on the other side of a capacitor, it's actual value doesn't matter, only that it is fixed.  You can therefore analyze the slew rate just as if the node is connected to ground.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post with PS section. Could you explain why the voltage across the current source M0 is almost zero?